# Mobaxterm Mercurial Plugin

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to access a local folder which is tracked under Mercurial through Mobaxterm, but it says `bash: hg: command not found`. I assume that I am missing a plugin, which is not listed under the official site. Has anyone managed to use Mercurial with Mobaxterm. Could you please point me to the right direction.

Comment: bash, the command shell, cannot find Mercurial. Is it in your path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just packaged mercurial (hg) for MobaXterm after seeing your post regarding it today. I only tested it briefly, so I can't guarantee it works perfectly.

See:
http://www.bananahut.net/software/mobaxterm-plugins